# show() and Hide() does not work in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have a div that needs to show error messages only when an error occurs, so I need to hide this div always, doesn't seem to work in IE11, no issues on other versions of IE10,IE9,IE8...
version of being used jQuery 1.8.0.
Any work arounds...

```
        <tr id="ErrorMsgRw">
                        <div id="ErrorMsgDiv" class="ErrorMsg">
                            <img id="Error" alt="An Error occurred" src="../Content/Images/Warning_icon.png" style="width: 20px; float: left; margin-right: 30px;" />
                            <b id="ErrorMsg" class="ErrorMsg"></b>
                            <a title="Close Error Bar" onclick="CloseErrorBar()">
                                <img id="Close" alt="Close this Message" src="../Content/Images/Close_icon.png" style="width: 20px; float: right;" /></a>
                        </div>
        </tr>


        function SetContent(DataToBeBound) {
        //Set Content
        $("#content").empty();
        $("#MessageTemplate").tmpl(DataToBeBound).appendTo("#content");
        if (DataToBeBound.IsAddSectionSet) { indexCount = 0; maxIndexCount = 0; $("#AddTemplate").tmpl(DataToBeBound).appendTo("#content"); $("#TreatyRate").attr("disabled", "disabled"); }//RetainData(); }
        $("#GridTemplate").tmpl(DataToBeBound).appendTo("#content");
        bindKeyPressToSearch();
        HideGridExtensions();
        $("#ErrorMsgRw").hide();
        }
```

Thanks in adv
HRg

Comment: Please provide the code and error message.

Comment: Don't you have the ID of ErrorMsgRw assigned to a <tr> element and not a <div>?

Comment: Should I avoid having a div inside a tr?

Comment: Also: `//RetainData(); }` <- comments out the closing bracket of `if`

Comment: You should have a `td` in your row, and place the div in that

Comment: Also, if you need it hidden by default, then set `display: none;` style

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will try and incorporate the changes mentioned in the comments sectioon... will get back again with findings...